# Gmail bulk Emails manipulation

Tags: gmail, google-apps-script, gmail-search

I am trying to deal with 600,000+ emails in inbox, my goal is to either delete or archive emails before 1/1/2021.

Doing a search and select all search results and then delete or archive as most people know will result in the action being applied to a couple of thousands emails at a time 2,000-6,000 sometimes as high as 25,000 but it's not consistent.

I tried to use the script provided [here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/141421/286007) and it worked for like 200,000 emails then I reached the *"Service invoked too many times for one day"* Which [means](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/troubleshooting?hl=en#service_invoked_too_many_times_action_name) That I hit the daily limit for execution, when I tried in another day I got the "Exceeded maximum execution time" error after a short while and only about 5,000 emails were processed.

The script I am using

```
function batchArchiveEmail() {
  var batchSize = 100 // Process up to 100 threads at once
  var searchSize = 500 // Limit search result to a max of 500 threads.
  //Use this if you encounter the "Exceeded maximum execution time" error "funny enough it didn't help that much".
  
  var threads = GmailApp.search('label:inbox before:2021/1/1', 0, searchSize);
  for (j = 0; j < threads.length; j+=batchSize) {
    GmailApp.moveThreadsToArchive(threads.slice(j, j+batchSize));
  }
}
```

In the comments user "acm" mentioned the usage of 'paged' call "[Google's preferred method](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#searchquery)", but unfortunately didn't post his script.

Google Apps script doesn't have a detailed documentation about this call and all I could find was this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58964273), but I fail to understand how to implement/ use this call to process emails based on date since it appears to me it retrieves a list of emails starting from the most recent and I can't figure out how to use it along with a date like user "acm" did.

If anyone have another way to achieve what I want to do please do tell.

Answer (score 3):

Try the following script

```
/**
 * Creates the first trigger to call batchArchiveEmail. 
 */
function init(){
   ScriptApp
    .newTrigger('batchArchiveEmail')
    .timeBased()
    .after(60 * 1000)
    .create();
    console.log(`trigger created`)
}

/**
 * Archive emails by batches preventing controlling limiting the execution time and  
 * creating a trigger if there are still threads pending to be archived.
 */ 
function batchArchiveEmail(){
  const start = Date.now();
  /** 
   * Own execution time limit for the search and archiving operations to prevent an 
   * uncatchable error. As the execution time check is done in do..while condition there  
   * should be enough time to one search and archive operation and to create a trigger 
   * to start a new execution. 
   */ 
  const maxTime = 25 * 60 * 1000; // Instead of 25 use 3 for Google free accounts
  const batchSize = 100;
  let threads, elapsedTime;
  /** Search and archive threads, then repeat until the search returns 0 threads or the 
   * maxTime is reached
   */ 
  do {
    threads = GmailApp.search('label:inbox before:2021/1/1');
    // console.log(`${threads[0] ? threads[0].getFirstMessageSubject() : 'No more threads'}`)
    for (let j = 0; j < threads.length; j += batchSize) {
      GmailApp.moveThreadsToArchive(threads.slice(j, j + batchSize));
    };
    /**
     * Used to prevent to have too many calls in a short time, might not be 
     * necessary with a large enough batchSize
     */
    Utilities.sleep(`2000`); 
    elapsedTime = Date.now() - start;
  } while (threads.length > 0 &&  elapsedTime < maxTime);
  if(threads.length > 0){
    /** Delete the last trigger */
    deleteTriggers();

    /** Create a one-time new trigger */
    ScriptApp
    .newTrigger('batchArchiveEmail')
    .timeBased()
    .after(60 * 1000)
    .create();
    console.log(`trigger created`)
  } else {
    /** Delete the last trigger */
    deleteTriggers();
    console.log(`No more threads to archive`);
  }
}

/**
 * As there is a limit on the number of triggers that a user might have for each 
 * project, delete the triggers.
 */
function deleteTriggers(){
  var triggers = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();
  for (var i = 0; i < triggers.length; i++) {
  ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(triggers[i]);
  }
}
```

Please note the use of `do...while`, `if` statement that creates a time-driven trigger, and the `deleteTriggers` function which is needed to prevent the archiving process being interrupted by a "This script has too many triggers" error.

---

Your are trying to find how to handle a large number email threads / messages and you get stuck on how to deal with Google Apps Script quotas.

Regarding "Service using too much computer time for one day" (from questions's rev 1), according to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quota), this error usually is caused by scripts being called by a trigger but might also get this error when running manually computer time intensive scripts.

Unfortunately there is no way to get more computer time for the account that got this message, the only workaround is to use a second account, but this will lead to use a more complex script, starting by  by using UrlFetchApp Service to call the Gmail API instead of the Google Apps Script Gmail Service and the Gmail Advanced Service, and implies to use Google OAuth.  There is GitHub repository / library published by Google to help with this but it's very likely that this is beyond of what you are looking, so it's very likely that the best will be to 1, improve the efficiency of your script, and 2 use a time-driven trigger and appropriate algorithm to run your script daily until all the messages were processed.

NOTE: It looks that is not feasible to migrate the account to a Google Workspace Account which have bigger quotas. I have not reviewed yet Google Workspace Individual plan, I'm wondering if it offers to increase the Google Apps Script quotas.

Regarding "Service invoked too many times for one day", according to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quota) the most common cause is to call the function from a Google Sheets custom function. It's unclear why is this happening to the  user who reported this to you.

Regarding using "'paged' call", this means to use `search(query, start, max)` instead of `search(query)` which is already used on your code but it's not taking advantage of how it works. The script above is not using it because I found that this is not really needed as nowadays `search(query) returns a maximum of 500 threads.

Comment: I might be wrong about the whole "Service using too much computer time for one day.". What happened was that after a certain amount of time my script would throw an error and won't run again until 24 hrs have passed. The problem is I couldn't remember what the error was so after some searching I thought that this error was the one I had and it meant to wait 24 hrs. But anyway I can reuse my old script normally after 24 hrs whenever I hit the limit.

Comment: I will try your script the very next time I come across a user that has 100,000+ emails since the other user has already been dealt with manually.

Comment: @Mostafa Please review the script executions page to review error messages and update the question accordingly.  P.S. I updated this answer's script.

Comment: I asked the user to send me the _"Summary of failures for Google Apps Script Email"_ and the error was "Service invoked too many times for one day", I also edited my original question.

Comment: I have noticed that you removed the "4 * 60 * 1000" part and just kept the "27 * 60 * 1000" any reason for that ? Quotas won't matter in the script current state weather the account was individual or Workspace ?

Comment: @Mostafa Quotas depend on the account type, for details see https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quota . P.S answer updated.

Comment: So I have tried the script with a "G Suite free edition (legacy)" user, replacing the "25" in "25 * 60 * 1000" with a "3" and what happened is that a trigger was created, some 1000+ emails were archived and after about 10 seconds from running the script the trigger was marked with a disabled state, it stayed that way for like 15 min until I deleted the trigger manually and rerun the script only for the whole situation to be repeated again. After a couple more times I gave up.

Comment: Update: I have tried the script again and although the trigger become disabled I found it was still running in the background (it runs for approximately 270 Sec.) and then it's state turns from running to completed (in execution history) and nothing happens after that it doesn't get deleted automatically nor a new trigger is created. I don't know how much time I should wait but when the trigger is disabled and it's states is "completed" and it stays that way for like 5 min I can't expect it to still delete itself and create a new trigger right ?

Comment: I added some comments and a deleteTriggers call on else statement. Please bear in mind that when the search returns 0 threads the script will not create new trigger.